# day wise contingency table in R using table()

Tags: r, data.table

I have a datatable with timestamp, temperature and status columns. I am trying to find out a contingency table in R using some frequency ranges. Now I am getting it. I have a column for timestamp in my data. I need to get day wise contingency table.

```
result = as.data.frame(table(cut(df$temp,breaks=c(0,30,60,80,100,1000),labels=c("0-30","30-60","60-80","80-100","100>"))))
```

Output :

```
Var1    Freq
0-30    1398
30-60   1051
60-80   1006
80-100  36
100>    2
```

Expected output:

```
Date             Var1    Freq
05-01-2020      0-30    1398
05-01-2020      30-60   1051
05-01-2020      60-80   1006
05-01-2020      80-100  36
05-01-2020      100>    2
06-01-2020      0-30    1398
06-01-2020      30-60   1051
06-01-2020      60-80   1006
06-01-2020      80-100  36
06-01-2020      100>    2
```

Also, I have status column with 1 and 0 as values. How to add that also along with date in the output.

Comment: Please be more precise. Where do your timestamps/date come from? What is the connection to your status column?

Comment: so i guess you have another column called Date for timestamp, you just need to split the data.frame you have and do the cut and table. How do you want to summarize the status?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [applying cut() on R dataframe daywise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62120876/3817004).

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output with some created dates:

```r
library(lubridate)

df <- read_table2("Var1    Freq
0-30    1398
30-60   1051
60-80   1006
80-100  36
100>    2")

date <- data.frame(Date=seq(dmy("05-01-2020"), length=2, by="1 day"))

df <- merge(df, date, all=TRUE)
df
# > df
#      Var1 Freq       Days
# 1    0-30 1398 2020-01-05
# 2   30-60 1051 2020-01-05
# 3   60-80 1006 2020-01-05
# 4  80-100   36 2020-01-05
# 5    100>    2 2020-01-05
# 6    0-30 1398 2020-01-06
# 7   30-60 1051 2020-01-06
# 8   60-80 1006 2020-01-06
# 9  80-100   36 2020-01-06
# 10   100>    2 2020-01-06
```