# applying cut() on R dataframe daywise

Tags: r, data.table

I have a datatable in R on which I apply a `cut()` and `table()`. I am able to get the frequency table based on the conditions. But I am getting overall frequencies. I want to get it day wise. I have a column named as `timestamp` which have timestamp. Also I have a `section` column which has value either `A` or `B`. How to cut it based on each day each section.

My current output :

```
Var1    Freq
0-30    1398
30-60   1051
60-80   1006
80-100  36
100>    2
```

Expected output:

```
Date        Sec  Var1    Freq
05-01-2020   A   0-30    1398
05-01-2020   A   30-60   1051
05-01-2020   A   60-80   1006
05-01-2020   A   80-100  36
05-01-2020   A   100>    2
05-01-2020   B   0-30    138
05-01-2020   B   30-60   151
05-01-2020   B   60-80   1056
05-01-2020   B   80-100  3
05-01-2020   B   100>    6
06-01-2020   A   0-30    398
06-01-2020   A   30-60   11
06-01-2020   A   60-80   16
06-01-2020   A   80-100  3666
06-01-2020   A   100>    25
06-01-2020   B   0-30    1948
06-01-2020   B   30-60   233
06-01-2020   B   60-80   33
06-01-2020   B   80-100  433
06-01-2020   B   100>    34
and so on.....
```

My code :

```
result = as.data.frame(table(cut(df$temp,breaks=c(0,30,60,80,100,1000),labels=c("0-30","30-60","60-80","80-100","100>"))))
```

Sample data :

```
timestamp        section    temp
01-05-2020 00:01:22 A   45
02-05-2020 00:01:22 A   10
03-05-2020 00:01:22 A   98
04-05-2020 00:01:22 A   23
05-05-2020 00:01:22 A   67
06-05-2020 00:01:22 A   89
07-05-2020 00:01:22 A   100
08-05-2020 00:01:22 A   110
09-05-2020 00:01:22 A   123
10-05-2020 00:01:22 A   12
01-05-2020 00:01:22 B   23
02-05-2020 00:01:22 B   44
03-05-2020 00:01:22 B   55
04-05-2020 00:01:22 B   12
05-05-2020 00:01:22 B   98
06-05-2020 00:01:22 B   45
07-05-2020 00:01:22 B   87
08-05-2020 00:01:22 B   65
09-05-2020 00:01:22 B   12
10-05-2020 00:01:22 B   8
```

Comment: What is your input

Comment: Input is a data table with 3 columns. `timestamp`, `section` and `temp`. `section` is either `A` or `B` always and `temp` is temperature  ranging from 0 to 150

Comment: Could you please help me with this ?

Comment: In your df$temp, what is 'temp'

Comment: temp column.... column which corresponds to temperature.

Comment: Can you please update with the input example so that it is more clear

Comment: I posted a solution.  Please check.  It's not tested, but I think it would work based on the code you showed

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], e.g.  This will help to prepare a proper answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option.  We do the grouping by 'Date' and the `cut` on the 'temp' column, then `summarise` to get the frequency with `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
    group_by(Date = as.Date(dmy_hms(timestamp)), section,
     Var1 = cut(temp, breaks=c(0,30,60,80,100,1000),
           labels=c("0-30","30-60","60-80", "80-100", "100>"))) %>%
    summarise(Freq = n())
# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   Date, section [20]
#   Date       section Var1    Freq
#   <date>     <chr>   <fct>  <int>
# 1 2020-05-01 A       30-60      1
# 2 2020-05-01 B       0-30       1
# 3 2020-05-02 A       0-30       1
# 4 2020-05-02 B       30-60      1
# 5 2020-05-03 A       80-100     1
# 6 2020-05-03 B       30-60      1
# 7 2020-05-04 A       0-30       1
# 8 2020-05-04 B       0-30       1
# 9 2020-05-05 A       60-80      1
#10 2020-05-05 B       80-100     1
#11 2020-05-06 A       80-100     1
#12 2020-05-06 B       30-60      1
#13 2020-05-07 A       80-100     1
#14 2020-05-07 B       80-100     1
#15 2020-05-08 A       100>       1
#16 2020-05-08 B       60-80      1
#17 2020-05-09 A       100>       1
#18 2020-05-09 B       0-30       1
#19 2020-05-10 A       0-30       1
#20 2020-05-10 B       0-30       1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(timestamp = c("01-05-2020 00:01:22", "02-05-2020 00:01:22", 
"03-05-2020 00:01:22", "04-05-2020 00:01:22", "05-05-2020 00:01:22", 
"06-05-2020 00:01:22", "07-05-2020 00:01:22", "08-05-2020 00:01:22", 
"09-05-2020 00:01:22", "10-05-2020 00:01:22", "01-05-2020 00:01:22", 
"02-05-2020 00:01:22", "03-05-2020 00:01:22", "04-05-2020 00:01:22", 
"05-05-2020 00:01:22", "06-05-2020 00:01:22", "07-05-2020 00:01:22", 
"08-05-2020 00:01:22", "09-05-2020 00:01:22", "10-05-2020 00:01:22"
), section = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), temp = c(45L, 
10L, 98L, 23L, 67L, 89L, 100L, 110L, 123L, 12L, 23L, 44L, 55L, 
12L, 98L, 45L, 87L, 65L, 12L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: Please see my sample data.. On same day at different time we will have different temperature. I need to group itinto those ranges and get the count per range,per section,per day.

Comment: @VJD please check my update.  I converted it to datetime and then get the Date alone

Comment: I am getting section, timestamp and temperature itself.. and no the summary of counts per section per day

Comment: @VJD I updated the code `Date = as.Date(dmy_hms(timestamp))`

Comment: Still I get the same

Comment: @VJD What you are getting now?  It is impossible to get `timestamp` column

Comment: it is working,,, But my last condition is coming as `NA` instead of 100>. This is happening ins var1 column

Comment: @VJD Is it based on the same data?  I don't get any NAs with this data

Comment: It is coming instead of "100>" label

Comment: @VJD it is possible that you have some groups that don't satisfy the breaks condition in your original data

Comment: But I have frequency for those values. Also is there any way to exclude those if breaks condition is not met

Comment: @VJD You can wrap with `na.omit`, so remove the `NA` rows

Comment: `Error: Column `Var1` must be length 21887 (the number of rows) or one, not 5947` I got this error

Comment: @VJD AFter the summarise, step `%>% ungroup %>% na.omit`

Answer (score 0):

This question has been tagged with `data.table`. So, for the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Freq = .N), 
          by = .(Date = as.IDate(timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y"), section,
                 Var1 = cut(temp, c(0, 30, 60, 80, 100, Inf), c("0-30", "30-60", "60-80", "80-100", "100>")))]
```

> ```
>           Date section   Var1 Freq
>  1: 2020-05-01       A  30-60    1
>  2: 2020-05-02       A   0-30    1
>  3: 2020-05-03       A 80-100    1
>  4: 2020-05-04       A   0-30    1
>  5: 2020-05-05       A  60-80    1
>  6: 2020-05-06       A 80-100    1
>  7: 2020-05-07       A 80-100    1
>  8: 2020-05-08       A   100>    1
>  9: 2020-05-09       A   100>    1
> 10: 2020-05-10       A   0-30    1
> 11: 2020-05-01       B   0-30    1
> 12: 2020-05-02       B  30-60    1
> 13: 2020-05-03       B  30-60    1
> 14: 2020-05-04       B   0-30    1
> 15: 2020-05-05       B 80-100    1
> 16: 2020-05-06       B  30-60    1
> 17: 2020-05-07       B 80-100    1
> 18: 2020-05-08       B  60-80    1
> 19: 2020-05-09       B   0-30    1
> 20: 2020-05-10       B   0-30    1
> ```

or, in a more programmatic way

```
breaks <- c(0, 30, 60, 80, 100, Inf)
labels <- stringr::str_replace(paste(head(breaks, -1L), tail(breaks, -1L), sep = "-"), "-Inf", ">")
setDT(df)[, .(Freq = .N), by = .(Date = as.IDate(timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y"), section,
                                 Var1 = cut(temp, breaks, labels))]
```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
  "timestamp time       section    temp
01-05-2020 00:01:22 A   45
02-05-2020 00:01:22 A   10
03-05-2020 00:01:22 A   98
04-05-2020 00:01:22 A   23
05-05-2020 00:01:22 A   67
06-05-2020 00:01:22 A   89
07-05-2020 00:01:22 A   100
08-05-2020 00:01:22 A   110
09-05-2020 00:01:22 A   123
10-05-2020 00:01:22 A   12
01-05-2020 00:01:22 B   23
02-05-2020 00:01:22 B   44
03-05-2020 00:01:22 B   55
04-05-2020 00:01:22 B   12
05-05-2020 00:01:22 B   98
06-05-2020 00:01:22 B   45
07-05-2020 00:01:22 B   87
08-05-2020 00:01:22 B   65
09-05-2020 00:01:22 B   12
10-05-2020 00:01:22 B   8")[
  , c("timestamp", "time") := .(paste(timestamp, time), NULL)]
```